# How to execute multiple Jmeter scripts and generate html report for those scripts

Tags: jmeter, report

I have multiple jmeter scripts like Test1.jmx,Test2.jmx,Test3.jmx and those scripts should be run sequentially and need to result file as HTML report.
And I had executed sequentially via bat but reports were generated individually(3reports)
I need single HTML report file for whole execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend option 1 in answer#1 to generate the [HTML dashboard report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) at the end of the test execution

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t TestPlan-1.jmx -f -l test-results-sample.csv
./jmeter.sh -n -t TestPlan-2.jmx -l test-results-sample.csv
./jmeter.sh -n -t TestPlan-3.jmx -l test-results-sample.csv
./jmeter.sh -g test-results-sample.csv -f -o test_reports
```

**Commanline options:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The options are in:

1. Execute your tests providing the same [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) via `-l` command line argument

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result.jtl
   jmeter -n -t test2.jmx -l result.jtl
   jmeter -n -t test3.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   as long as you don't use `-f` argument the result file will be appended.

   More information: [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
2. Use [Merge Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)  (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))